# How can I extract just the seconds from the timestamp?

Tags: groovy

How can I use Groovy to extract just seconds from a `java.sql.Timestamp`?

I have used the following code to extract the time

```
def time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

This gives me the following output:

```
2018-01-24 13:56:19.444
```

It would be helpful if I get just the seconds and nanos (**19.444**).

I am developing a Groovy script to make a difference between my default timer(sec) and real time in sec.

Comment: why not just divide the difference in milliseconds by 1000 ?!

Comment: That's millis, surely, not nanos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's milliseconds, not nanoseconds.  Another way to get it (assuming you want it in a `double`, and assuming you are using Java 8), would be via the `java.time` classes:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.temporal.TemporalField

// I assume this comes from a database
def time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())

double secondsAndMillis = time.toInstant().with { instant ->
    instant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).until(instant, ChronoUnit.MILLIS) / 1000d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have all to do it:

```
def time = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
println "${time.seconds}.${time.nanos}"
```